# php only allow letters, numbers, spaces and specific symbols using pregmatch

Tags: php, regex, string, validation, preg-match

on my php i use `preg_match` to validate input texts.

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $firstname)) {
}
```

But this only allows alphanumeric and does not allow spaces. I want to allow spaces, alpha and numeric. and period(.) and dash(-)

Please help me out here? thanks in advance.

Comment: Just try add that all in your regex.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 .\-]+$/i', $firstname)
```

Comment: As a rule, I tend to avoid simply a white space in the regex (since it could actually represent a number of different characters depending on the encoding of your editor) and be explicit by using `\040`.

Comment: @HorusKol So how do you do that?

Comment: `'/^[a-z0-9\040\.\-]+$/i'`

Comment: I need  alphanumeric,\,/,- symbols.others are not allowed

Answer (score 20):

If you not only want to allow ASCII, then use [Unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop):

```
preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N} .-]+$/', $firstname)
```

`\p{L}` is any letter in **any** language, matches also Chinese, Hebrew, Arabic, ... characters.

`\p{N}` any kind of numeric character (means also e.g. roman numerals)

if you want to limit to digits, then use `\p{Nd}`

Comment: if you want to internationalize, why not using `\p{N}` instead of `0-9`

Comment: I believe that you should add an 'u' modifier if this is to work properly in PHP. Like this:
preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N} .-]+$/u', $firstname)

Comment: @Larpon, Unicode properties are working without the [`u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). You need that modifier, when your regex string contains UTF8 characters.

Comment: @stema ok - I just couldn't get your exact example to work without it in PHP 5.5.3 - my `$firstname` variable contains unicode characters.
Could be that `\p{L}` in a sense is unicode - I wouldn't know :)

Comment: Future debuggers should know that Larpon's comment took me from not-working to working. Thus, it is important.

Answer (score 4):

The only difficult bit here is the dash.

For spaces and dots, you can simply add them to your character class, like so:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9 .]+$/'
```

Easy.

The dash is slightly harder because hyphens have special meaning in a character class like this (as you already know, they're used for ranges of characters like `a-z`). In order to specify a hyphen in a character class, it must be the first character in the class (ie it must not be between two characters, otherwise it is treated as a character range marker).

So your expression would be:

```
'/^[-a-zA-Z0-9 .]+$/'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes this helps. now i'm even understanding further the right syntax'es for preg_match function.

Comment: Does not have to be first character for dash, you can escape it using `\\`